# Django : Error when starting supervisorctl : ImportError at / No module named ___

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that I restart with the commands

```
ubuntu@ip-1234:~$sudo supervisorctl restart myapp

myapp: stopped
myapp: started

ubuntu@ip-1234:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
ubuntu@ip-1234:~$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

However, when I got to my domain (debug=True) I get the error:

```
ImportError at /
No module named pdfrw
```

However, if I navigate back to my app and try to download the package

```
ubuntu@ip-1234:~$sudo -i -u myapp
myapp@ip-1234:~$ pip install pdfrw
Requirement already satisfied: pdfrw in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'm not sure why it isn't finding this package in production. I used to be able to get this working, I imagine something is wrong with where my packages are being installed. My application works fine if I remove the `from pdfrw import PdfDict` line I have in my code. Perhaps something to do with permissions?

My supervisor config at /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp.conf

```
[program:myapp]
command = /webapps/program:myapp_django/bin/gunicorn_start                    ; Command to start app
user = program:myapp                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /webapps/program:myapp_django/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

Comment: Is it using the same instance of python that you're testing with? Try `which python` to help work that out.

Comment: @Shadow whether I'm in myapp or ubuntu I get "/usr/bin/python"

Comment: It'll be to do with the python path that myapp is using. Are you able to post the supervisor conf for myapp?

Comment: @WillKeeling Added it above -- doesn't appear that I changed anything

Comment: your supervisor config doesn't have `myapp` please post any conf file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` directory that has `myapp`

Comment: @sipp11 Updated -- thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

`pip install --target=lib/python2.7/site-packages pdfrw`

I was installing packages to the wrong location.